# DLL include in exe.file?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, exe

I build a project in C#.
From another project I have 5 DLLs.

Is It possible to include the DLL in the exe, that I only give 1 File to people and not x files?

I tried ILMerge, but the output file ever opened a Command prompt with the application - useless.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can merge the exe and the dlls with the [ILMerge.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/DownLoads/details.aspx?FamilyID=22914587-b4ad-4eae-87cf-b14ae6a939b0&displaylang=en) tool

```
lmerge.exe /out:C:\SomePath\TheOnlyOneExe.exe 
    C:\....\bin\Debug\someexe.exe C:\....\bin\Debug\somedll.dll /t:exe
```

Comment: Wow I didn't know about this tool. Thanks for it! I was gonna reply that you can just copy the dll source files in your main program and compile it like that, but after your reply, it's not worth it anymore ;)

Comment: I tried, but every time I start the output DLL a command prompt open with it, is it normal?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ILMerage](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx)

You can download it from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=22914587-b4ad-4eae-87cf-b14ae6a939b0&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old issue, but for anyone thats looking for an answer I found the following link helpful for my situation. The following will also work for WPF.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx

This method lets you embed dlls into your assembly by adding them to your project and set the Build Action property to Embedded Resource. The article does a good job of explaining this.