# Path to exe in dll when used in ASP.NET MVC Application in Debug

Tags: c#, dll, path, exe

I've written a wrapper for a 3rd party exe. The exe is in a folder inside my class library project and is deployed with the dll.

Unit testing the method that starts the process containing this exe works fine but when I use the dll inside by web application, the exe cannot be found.

Debugging I see that the path to the exe is not correct when used from my web application.

I've tried:

```
string processPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"folder\file.exe");
```

and

```
string processPath = Path.GetFullPath(@"folder\file.exe");
```

as well as simply:

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"folder\file.exe");
```

Is there something I can use to refer to the folder relative to where the dll is stored (i.e. in the bin for my web app)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Executable:

```
string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

.dll

```
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyClass)).CodeBase);
```

might need

```
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
```

Or You can use:

You can merge the exe and the dlls with the ILMerge.exe tool

```
lmerge.exe /out:C:\SomePath\TheOnlyOneExe.exe 
C:\....\bin\Debug\someexe.exe C:\....\bin\Debug\somedll.dll /t:exe
```

Found this on another post
[DLL include in exe.file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400376/dll-include-in-exe-file)

Comment: Not sure if this is what you meant but thought I'd try to help.

Comment: That's great Mac thanks. The only thing I had to do was remove the first 6 characters ("file:\") from the beginning of the path.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Server.MapPath`. This will return the right directory.

Comment: Where is Server.MapPath? I know I can use that within a web app but I don't seem to be able to do that from inside my class library. It's the class library that uses the exe.

Comment: So I see I can use that if I include a Reference to System.Web in my class library. Is there a way that doesn't involve doing this?

Comment: System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/")